# Why is this jQuery POST call, using FormData, to upload a file, not successfully making the call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble debugging this simple file, for testing whether my upload page is working correctly. The code looks correct from my eyes, but it's not running right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button_a").click(function(){
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.post("./../pages/upload_image.php", formData, function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Test upload_image.php</h2>
    <form onsubmit="return false" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" placeholder="File...">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <br />
    <button id="button_a">Upload</button>
    </br>
    </br>
    <h3>Output:</h3>
    <div id="content" style="padding: 50px; background-color: #CCC;">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your html is missing a closing form tag

Answer (score 0):

Quick look shows you using

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

try changing it to :

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

I think your context of $(this) is the Anchor tag, not the form.